# Schedule a report in BI publisher through web Services

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to Schedule a report in BI publisher through web Services.

After I am passing the required parameters to the ScheduleReport method,
I have to get job_id. But the problem is I didn't get any resposes and also it doesn't produce any error.

How can I solve this isssue? Somebodies can help me out of it.Thanks in Advance.
I have attached my code below.

```
package com.bip.client;

    import com.bip.services.ArrayOfParamNameValue;
    import com.bip.services.ArrayOfString;
    import com.bip.services.ReportDefinition;
    import com.bip.services.ReportRequest;
    import com.bip.services.ReportResponse;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
    import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;

public class PublicReportServiceClient {

@WebServiceRef
private static PublicReportServiceService publicReportServiceService;

public static void main(String[] arg) throws MalformedURLException, AccessDeniedException
{
       publicReportServiceService = new PublicReportServiceService();
 try
     {
      //Creating client class for the above mention BIP URL.      
      URL url;
      url = new URL("http://localhost:7001/xmlpserver/services/PublicReportService");

    QName qname;
    qname = new QName("http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService", "PublicReportServiceService");

    publicReportServiceService = new PublicReportServiceService(url, qname);
    PublicReportService publicReportService;
    publicReportService = publicReportServiceService.getPublicReportService();

    String sessionId;
    sessionId = publicReportService.login("weblogic", "weblogic123");
    System.out.println("sessionId : " + sessionId);

    ArrayOfString values = new ArrayOfString();
    values.getItem().add("AT1"); //value of the input parameter

    ReportDefinition reportDef = publicReportService.getReportDefinitionInSession("/~weblogic/account_details.xdo", sessionId);
    ArrayOfParamNameValue valArray = reportDef.getReportParameterNameValues();

    ArrayOfString parameter = reportDef.getParameterNames();
    for(int i=0; i<parameter.getItem().size(); i++)
       {               
         System.out.println("Cols : "+parameter.getItem().get(i));
         valArray.getItem().get(i).setValues(values);
       }

    //Creating ReportRequest object and set required values
    ReportRequest req = new ReportRequest();
    req.setAttributeFormat("pdf"); //type of the report
    req.setAttributeLocale("en-US"); //Language
    req.setAttributeTemplate("Simple"); //Template type
    req.setReportAbsolutePath("/~weblogic/account_details.xdo"); //Absolute path of the report from BIP Catalog.
    req.setSizeOfDataChunkDownload(-1); //to download all
    req.setParameterNameValues(valArray);

    //Create ReportResponse object to create report based on ReportRequest object.
    ReportResponse res;
    res = new ReportResponse();
    res = publicReportService.runReportInSession(req, sessionId);

    ScheduleRequest sreq = new ScheduleRequest();
    sreq.setReportRequest(req);//Set ReportRequest 
    //Set scheduling information 
    sreq.setNotificationTo("abcde@xxx.com"); 
    sreq.setSaveDataOption(true); 
    sreq.setBookBindingOutputOption(false); 
    sreq.setMergeOutputOption(true);
    sreq.setNotifyWhenFailed(true);
    sreq.setNotifyWhenSuccess(true);
    sreq.setNotifyWhenWarning(true);
    sreq.setRepeatCount(1);
    sreq.setUseUTF8Option(true);
    sreq.setScheduleBurstringOption(false); 
    sreq.setSchedulePublicOption(true); 
    sreq.setUserJobName("WebService Job1"); 
    sreq.setRepeatInterval(1);

    String job_id = publicReportService.scheduleReportInSession(sreq, sessionId); 
    System.out.println("job_id:"+ job_id);

    }catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
        System.out.println("given URL is invalid");
        murle.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AccessDeniedException ade) {
        System.out.println("invalid user id and password");
        ade.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidParametersException ipe) {
        ipe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationFailedException ofe) {
        ofe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

I'm getting this output,

```
sessionId : AF1E5BDDE84C5F24A78FFDE733F99101
Cols : BRANCH_CODE
job_id:
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late on the reply here, sorry...

[Here's a nice little summary of submitting a job](http://bipconsulting.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-schedule-report-with-bi.html)

Four steps from the linked page:

1. Create DeliveryRequest object
2. Create ReportRequest object
3. Create ScheduleRequest object
4. Call scheduleReportInSession() method

I'm new at this, but your doing two things here, running the report in real-time

```
//Create ReportResponse object to create report based on ReportRequest object.
ReportResponse res;
res = new ReportResponse();
res = publicReportService.runReportInSession(req, sessionId);
```

And also submitting the report to the BI Publishers scheduler.

```
String job_id = publicReportService.scheduleReportInSession(sreq, sessionId); 
System.out.println("job_id:"+ job_id);
```

Not sure if you meant to do that, after the runReportInSession() call you should have the pdf in the response object (res.getReportBytes()).

As far as the scheduler job id, I believe you need a delivery request object, or save the report output using setSaveOutputOption(true).

```
 EMailDeliveryOption em = new EMailDeliveryOption(); 
 em.setEmailTo("someone@somecompany.com"); 
 em.setEmailSubject("Here's your BI Publisher report..."); 
 em.setEmailFrom("me@mycompany.com"); 
 em.setEmailCC("myBoss@mycompany.com"); 
 em.setEmailBody("Here's your report"); 
 DeliveryRequest dr = new DeliveryRequest(); 
 dr.setEmailOption(em); 
 ...
//Set DeliveryRequest 
sreq.setDeliveryRequest(dr);
```